# Why does this model have 12 parameters?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, keras

I guess the model shown in this image (img_1)

[image]

is the same as [the one](https://youtu.be/fXOsFF95ifk?list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Ec-XTbcX1uRg2_u4xOEky0&t=123) in this image (img_2)

[image]

I was trying to build a neural net like that.

This keras code is to do the job.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

However, `print(model.summary())` outputs

```
Model: "sequential_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 12        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 4         
=================================================================
```

There are 3 `w`s and 1 `b` in the hidden layer. Why does this model have 12 parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 inputs going to 3 nodes in the input layer. Each connection has a weight so you have  3 X 3 =9 weights. Plus each node has a bias weight so that adds 3 more weights for a total of 12. Your output layer has 3 inputs and is a single node so you have 3 weights for the inputs to the node plus a bias weight for a total of 4. So the total weights in your network is 16.